# Bokeh line plot instead of starting the mid vbar stack, starting beginning of the vbar stack

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I wanted to plot the line beginning of the vbar stack graph instead of the mid position.

How can I do that? Or is that even possible? Thanks for helping me out. [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gzXR.png)

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import Title
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import Legend
from bokeh.io import export_svgs

output_file('stacked.html')

capacity = ['CO2_Cap', 'Min_RES_Quota', 'CO2_Tax', 'FIT']
types = ['Lignite', 'Coal', 'CCGT', 'OCGT','Wind Onshore', 'Wind Offshore', 'Solar']
colors = ["#9a7b5c", "#414141", "#c7dada", "#c7dada", "#5a67ff",'#00b8f2', '#fff340']

maxload = [90.03467675, 90.03467675, 90.03467675, 90.03467675]
Total_demand = [540.7686148, 540.7686148, 540.7686148, 540.7686148]


data = {'capacity' : capacity,
        'Lignite'   : [0,22.28330605,0,25.76575924],
        'Coal'   : [0, 0, 0,0],
        'CCGT'   : [52.12309276, 0.209356135, 52.12598273, 6.416971663],
        'OCGT'   : [10.1753325,20.35167058,10.1729694,22.18142626],
        'Wind Onshore': [90.66714923, 77.28982927, 90.6875821, 86.3713515],
        'Wind Offshore': [24.26075426, 53.92876756, 24.25201174, 60.265434],
        'Solar' : [90.1174063, 159.3567357, 90.0774928, 178.0811123]
        }

s1 = figure(x_range=capacity, plot_height=450,plot_width=655)


s1.vbar_stack(types, x='capacity', width=0.3, color=colors, source=data,
             legend=[value(x) for x in types], hatch_pattern=['dot', 'spiral', 'vertical_wave', 'right_diagonal_line', 'vertical_dash', 'left_diagonal_line', 'ring'])
s1.line(x = capacity, y = maxload, color="red", line_width=3, legend_label = "max_load")

s1.legend.location = "bottom_right"
s1.legend.click_policy="hide"
#s1.add_layout(Title(text="Total CO2 Emissions (in 10^6t) ", align="center"), "left")


show(s1)
```

Comment: The line would have different Y values at the left and at the right side of a single bar, but at the same time the Y value in the data is the same for the whole bar. Are you sure about that solution? You're trying to combine categorical, disparate, values with a single line - it doesn't make sense from the data perspective to use a line here because lines are generally for continuous data.

Comment: It's for sure to put a line because of showing the maximum load. I just wanted to show somehow the max load in it.

Answer (score 1):

The position of each vertical bar on the X axis is it's index in the categories list + 0.5. Given the vertical bar width `bar_width`, the straight line will go from `(s1.x_range.factors.index(capacity[0])+0.5-bar_width/2, 90.03467675)` to `(s1.x_range.factors.index(capacity[-1])+0.5+bar_width/2, 90.03467675)`.

The code to solve your question is available below. Please note that some minor changes were necessary for the code to run with bokeh==3.1.1 and python==3.8.2

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import Title
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import Legend, Span
from bokeh.io import export_svgs

output_file('stacked.html')

capacity = ['CO2_Cap', 'Min_RES_Quota', 'CO2_Tax', 'FIT']
types = ['Lignite', 'Coal', 'CCGT', 'OCGT','Wind Onshore', 'Wind Offshore', 'Solar']
colors = ["#9a7b5c", "#414141", "#c7dada", "#c7dada", "#5a67ff",'#00b8f2', '#fff340']

maxload = [90.03467675, 90.03467675]

data = {'capacity' : capacity,
        'Lignite'   : [0,22.28330605,0,25.76575924],
        'Coal'   : [0, 0, 0,0],
        'CCGT'   : [52.12309276, 0.209356135, 52.12598273, 6.416971663],
        'OCGT'   : [10.1753325,20.35167058,10.1729694,22.18142626],
        'Wind Onshore': [90.66714923, 77.28982927, 90.6875821, 86.3713515],
        'Wind Offshore': [24.26075426, 53.92876756, 24.25201174, 60.265434],
        'Solar' : [90.1174063, 159.3567357, 90.0774928, 178.0811123]
        }

s1 = figure(x_range=capacity, height=450, width=800)

bar_width = 0.3
s1.vbar_stack(types, x='capacity', width=bar_width, color=colors, source=data,
              legend_label=types, 
              hatch_pattern=['dot', 'spiral', 'vertical_wave', 'right_diagonal_line', 
                             'vertical_dash', 'left_diagonal_line', 'ring'],
              hatch_color="black")

s1.line(x = [s1.x_range.factors.index(capacity[0])+0.5-bar_width/2, 
             s1.x_range.factors.index(capacity[-1])+0.5+bar_width/2], 
        y = maxload, color="red", line_width=3, legend_label = "max_load")

s1.legend.location = "bottom_right"
s1.legend.click_policy="hide"

show(s1)
```

The result is the following
[image: example_plot]